# How to fold cabbage leaves for cooking?

Tags: cabbage

Is there a way to fold cabbage in a pot so that you maximize the amount you can fit?

I just split my cabbage head in 8 45° wedges and sort of flatten the leaves to layers. But I still was able to fit only one (albeit large) head plus some add ons and it's a 2 gal pot.

[image]

Comment: Maybe just boil halves/quarters of the head? It seems nature packed the leaves pretty tight. (though I prefer washing every leaf)

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the core from the cabbage completely. This can be done by slicing it in half and using a "v" like pattern for coring it. After the core is removed, all the leaves should flake off very easily. It is usually easier to fill more in a pot when you lay the leaves flat on top of each other. Alternatively, and with a bit more work, you can also just peel the leaves away from the core individually. This is a good way to get bigger leaves (especially useful when making stuffed cabbage).